# mysql: change value after compairing within same column

Tags: mysql

Here I want to update value for an id if it's value is 1 less than value of another id, and update it, then compare updated value again with other values.
**In simple language, consecutive values are checked, and value is replaced with the highest value in that sequence**.

```
ID          value
1           4
2           5
3           10
4           6
5           12
6           11
7           18
```

So, the final table would be like this.

```
ID          value
1           6
2           6
3           12
4           6
5           12
6           12
7           18
```

I tried it using join statements, but couldn't make it out.

Answer (score 2):

This should work if the ID column is sequential :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        This.ID,
        Value=MIN(X.Value)
    FROM 
        MyTable THIS
        LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable LAG ON LAG.Value = THIS.Value + 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT 
                This.ID,
                This.Value
            FROM 
                MyTable THIS
                LEFT OUTER JOIN @T LAG ON LAG.Value = THIS.Value + 1
            WHERE
                LAG.Value IS NULL
        )AS X ON X.Value >= THIS.Value 
    GROUP BY
        This.ID,
        This.Value
)AS Y
ORDER BY
    ID
```